# How to connect two objects as union precisely?

Tags: sketch-app, flatten

I'm now reading [this tutorial](http://airwalk-design.com/?cat=tutorials&inc=1744&stick=design-a-todo-list-app-icon-with-sketch-3) which describes how to create a simple to-do list iOS icon. On the tutorial, the author combines two rectangles as `union` in Sketch 3. However, when I tried to duplicate the project, it seems that I cannot combine the two rectangles precisely no matter how I try to be close to the precise point possible.

Here's my project. You can see that there is small disconnection on the combination point. I just duplicated the project with the exact same size and degree.

[image]

And of course even after I combined them as `union` and then make them `flatten`, the two objects never merge properly. I also tried to use grid but nothing changed at all.

So how can I combine two rectangles precisely, much like the author did?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up smart guides that will allow you to snap objects together at certain points in View > Guides > Smart Guides. Be sure that you also have Snap enabled.